# How can I remove black spots from the paintwork of my car?

Tags: cleaning, car

I have a 15 year old car, with black spots on the paintwork, in various places, in a spray pattern. I'd assume that these are tar spots, but I've tried various tar spot removal creams, and nothing seems to work. What else might they be, and how could I remove them (without ruining the paintwork)?

Comment: Welcome to Lifehacks! Can you include some more details? e.g., if the spots have any depth to them? A picture is worth a thousand words as well.

Comment: @Mooseman: Hi, I'll see what I can do re picture, but IIRC the spots have no real depth to them.

Comment: They are probably tar spots. Easiest way is to use the chemicals meant to remove them, i have tried cleaning them with various things i had at home but it is just a pain. The chemicals you can just spray on and wash off and be done with it.